# How to mark read mails as unread in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix

In our postfix server, the mail directories `cur` and `new` are under `/home/<user>/Maildir`. I don't have much of an experience with mail servers, but I am aware that new  e-mails land in the `new` folder first, and once read, they get moved to the `cur` folder.

```
[root@imap01 cur]# ls | head -5
1414497605.Vfd02I42dcbM893399.imap01.xyz.com:2,S
1414497605.Vfd02I42dceM901537.imap01.xyz.com:2,S
1414497606.Vfd02I42dcfM227925.imap01.xyz.com:2,S
1414584047.Vfd02I42deeM736282.imap01.xyz.com:2,S
1414584047.Vfd02I42df0M736415.imap01.xyz.com:2,S
[root@imap01 cur]#pwd
/home/userabc/Maildir/cur
[root@imap01 cur]#
```

The `:2,S` suffix is getting added to the files once they are moved to `cur`. Now my questions are:

- How can I mark a read mail as unread through commandline?
- Is it as simple as moving the mail from `cur` folder to `new` folder?
- Is it as simple as removing the `:2,S` suffix from the mail files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that all we had to do was to combine the last 2 steps I had asked in the question.

Copy the e-mail file, (ie. 141443305.abc123abc.imap01.xyz.com:2,S) from `/home/<user>/Maildir/cur` to `/home/<user>/Maildir/new` and rename it by removing the `:2,S` suffix. This process marks the read mail as unread.